# How can I recover btc that did not register to address

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I sent btc to davor coin from coinbase the night it crashed. Coinbase shows the transaction was accepted but I don't see my btc on the davor website. How can I recover my btc when davor is not responding

https://blockchain.info/address/16WArqNTvEYiZWgXXdfAPEQsgEubgNuYAq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Both the transactions shown in the link are confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

The transactions to/from the address you linked have been confirmed and cannot be reversed.  If you click on the transaction IDs (e.g. `cbbae668...`), you will see the number of confirmations; currently in the thousands.

> How can I recover my btc when davor is not responding?

You cannot.  Davor owns those coins now, and any attempt to do anything with them will need their cooperation.  All you can do is ask them to credit your account and/or refund their coins.  You can ask politely, or rudely, or with the assistance of the legal system (i.e. try to sue them).  But this is no longer a problem that can be solved via technology.